# Arranging the $k$ solutions of $r(z)=te^{i\theta}$ into $k$ continuous functions of $(t,\theta)$

Tags: cv.complex-variables, rational-functions, implicit-function-theorem

I have originally opened this question on MSE, but I migrated here, since I realized this environment is more suitable.

Let $r$ be a rational function, that is, quotient of two coprime polynomials $p,q\in\Bbb C[X]$. Assume
$$
r(z)=te^{i\theta}
$$
has $k$ distinct solutions $w_j(t,\theta)$, $j=1,\dots,k$, for any $t\ge T$ and $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$.

**Problem:** Is there a choice of $k$ continuous functions $(t,\theta)\mapsto z_j(t,\theta)$ such that
$$
r(z_j(t,\theta))=te^{i\theta}\;\;?
$$

I think using the Axiom of Choice we can define functions verifying the last equation for every $(t,\theta)\in(T,+\infty)\times[0,2\pi)$. They would be injective, but the problem is: how can we pick them to be continuous?

I would like to express
$$
\{z\in\overline{\Bbb C}\;:\;|r(z)|>T\}
$$
as the disjoint union of $k$ sets, each of which contains exactly one solution of $r(z)=b$, for any fixed $|b|>T$, and if the $z_j$ are continuous and injective then their image $S_j:=z_j((T,+\infty)\times[0,2\pi))$ would solve my problem.

**Example:** Consider the basic example of $r(z)=z^k$. It's clear that for every $a\neq0$, the equation $r(z)=a$ has $k$ distinct solutions. In this case, writing $a=te^{i\theta}$ as above, the solutions are
$$
w_j(t,\theta)=t^{1/k}e^{i\frac{\theta+2\pi j}k}\;,
$$
which are continuous and injective (no need to define $z_j$ this time), so in this basic case, such a choice does exist.
Then:

1. The $S_j$ defined as above are a partition of the set $\{z\in\overline{\Bbb C}\;:\;|r(z)|>T\}$, that is, they are disjoint and their union is the whole set.
2. Moreover, for every $a$ such that $|a|>T$, every $S_j$ contains exactly one solution of the equation $r(z)=a$.

This is a consequence of the fact that the solutions are arranged into $k$ different continuous injective functions. So, if this keeps holding for every rational function $r$ defined as above, then I could reach the same conclusions 1. and 2.

Comment: I imagine it would be easy to come up with a quadratic where you already cannot accomplish this parameterisation.  Probably 'monodromy' is the right term. \\ Also, your argument asks for functions of $s$, but there does not seem to be an $s$ in the problem.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo, I meant function of $a$

Comment: That is different from the question in the body.  If, for $k > 1$, you try to write down the $k$ roots of $a \ne 0$ as continuous functions of $a$ (not of the magnitude and an argument that is, crucially, restricted to $[0, 2\pi)$), then you will already run into trouble.

Comment: No, the body is right. I need this function depending on $(t,\theta)$